# Range, Kernel, Linear Teansformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let *T* be a linear transformation.
If range of *T* is subset of its kernel, then *T* must be a zero map? Is it possible that *T* is not a zero map?

Answer (score 1):

The condition $im(T) \subseteq ker(T)$ is equivalent to $T^2 = 0$. The other answers have given you examples nonzero linear transformations who square to zero, such as $(x, y) \mapsto (0, x)$.

Comment: Is it also true for $T^n$, say n > 2?

Comment: If you have a $T$ with $T^n = 0$ by $T^2 \neq 0$ then this will fail. Take, for example, $T: \mathbb R^3 \longrightarrow \mathbb R^3$ via $e_1 \mapsto e_2$, $e_2 \mapsto e_3$, $e_3 \mapsto 0$. Then $T^3 = 0$, but $T(e_1) = e_2$ is in $im(T)$ and $T(e_2) = e_3 \neq 0$. Hence, we have $e_2 \in im(T)$ and $e_2 \notin ker(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

On $\mathbb R^{2}$ define $T(x,y)=(0,x)$. In this case the range is contained in the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the linear transformation on $\Bbb R^2$ whose matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.